# jQuery how to remove dynamically appended rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

If I append rows to my table like this:

```
 $('#tbody_upload').append('<tr id="' + data.originalFiles[counter].name + '"><td>' + 'Uploading...' + '</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
```

how can I remove it from another event?

```
$('#' + this.name).remove();
```

that function doesn't work, also appended items don't appear in source of the page.

Comment: In your "other event", what does `this` represent? Also, appended items will not appear in the source, but you should be able to inspect the page using your browser's dev tools to see the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove the element that triggers the event to be removed (as appears from this.name) you can simply do

$(this).remove();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should name your table and then with a selector select the body and first errase it and then append data so every time you get new data, the table deletes the old data and puts the new one.

```
<table id="yourtableName" border="1" class="hoverTable">
<thead>

</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

var  gridBody = your tr code;

```
$('#yourtableName tbody').empty().append(gridBody);
```